# How to know the Total Number of Pages in Google Docs Viewer

Tags: javascript, html

I am using google docs viewer to show pdf files in my website. I want to show all page numbers to jump on any pages i want. which is working fine with following:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=myurl&embedded=true&a=bi&pagenumber=12 width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

But i want to get no of pages of the document.

Answer (score 0):

TCPDF Is the best pdf generator.And it is easily customizable.

- In the Tcpdf u can show the page number and custom header and footer.
- Stylesheet is also acceptable in tcpdf.
- Images.

Links
[Official Link for TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)

[You Can Find Various of Examples In this link about TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php)